# Expected number of times Random Walk crosses 0 line.

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose we have a simple random walk:

$$
x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}
$$

Where

$$
\epsilon_{t} =  iid\  \mathcal{N} (0,1)
$$

Assume that `x` starts at `0` what is the expected number of times `x` will cross the `0` point for `N` number of periods?

I am more interested in the method of obtaining the answer than the answer  itself.

What I have so far: I was looking at simple case where `N` = 2, and in this case expected number of crosses seems to be `0.25`. Intuitively, this makes sense, in the first period we moved somewhere, and on the second the probability that we move in the right direction is 0.5, and of that 0.5, the probability (on average) that we move back far enough to cross is 0.5, so 0.5 * 0.5 => 0.25.

I validated this with simulation:

```
import numpy as np

def simulations(n, n_iterations):
    return sum(my_one_run(n) for _ in xrange(n_iterations)) / float(n_iterations)

def my_one_run(n):
    path = [0]
    n_crosses = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        prev = path[-1]
        new_x = prev + np.random.normal(0,1)
        path.append(new_x)
        if prev * new_x < 0:
            n_crosses += 1
    return n_crosses
```

And my results have been confirmed:

```
In [66]: simulations(2, 1000000)
Out[66]: 0.250249
```

However, I don't see how to proceed for a more complicated case, even more general case.

(This is not a homework question, if this matters. I am just trying to explore something in this area and wanted to start with a basic case.).

Comment: Have you done any work? You should post your results, even if they're wrong, so we can help you identify any problem areas.

Comment: @Zach466920, I updated the question with what I got. Any hint or direction would be useful.

Comment: You should write $\epsilon_t$ and mention that they are iid $N(0,1)$. As it stands, what you've written is $x_t=t \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is *one* $N(0,1)$ variable. Nice question, though. I'll remark that if you rescale time, so that $x_{t+\delta}=x_t+\sqrt{\delta}\epsilon_t$ where $\delta>0$, then as $\delta \to 0^+$ you get Brownian motion, for which the expected number of crossings is $+\infty$ in any finite time interval. (Actually, the number of crossings is $+\infty$ with probability $1$ in this case.)

Comment: @Ian, thanks for your comment, but I am not sure that I understand it. Are you saying if time interval approaches 0, the number of crosses infinity? But what if x changed set `N` of times?

Comment: @Akavall If the time step goes to zero (in the way that I described) and the time interval is held fixed, then the number of crossings goes to infinity. But of course this means that the number of *steps* also goes to infinity.

Comment: @Ian, ah OK, I think I understood that :), but what about the case where number steps is fixed, say, N? That should happen if time step is constant. That's the case that I am interested mostly in.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your case. The tricky thing is that a crossing can't be described only by a state, instead you're counting exits into and out of a set. Even worse, you never hit the boundary of this set (the process simply jumps through the boundary). This means a lot of the standard tricks for this sort of thing don't work, at least as far as I can tell. You might consider the related case where $\epsilon=B_n-n/2$ where $B_n$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p=1/2$. Then the state space is countable and only finitely many states are accessible from each state. That simplifies life.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The location density after $n$ moves is
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{n}}f\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
Given that we are currently at $x$, the probability that we will cross the origin on the next move is
$$
\int_{t\ge|x|}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
So the probability that on move $n+1$, we cross the origin is
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{t\ge|x|}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}f\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{t\ge|x|\sqrt{n}}f(x)f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which is the probability that given a Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that we end up in the wedge $\{(x,t):t\ge|x|\sqrt{n}\}$, which is
$$
p_n=\frac1\pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
Thus, the expected number of zero-crossings in $n$ moves would be
$$
e_n=\frac1\pi\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\right)
$$
Apply this to $n=2$, and we get $\frac14$ precisely.

Here is a short table
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
n&e_n\\
\hline
2&0.250000\\
3&0.445913\\
4&0.612580\\
5&0.760164\\
6&0.894024\\
7&1.017400\\
8&1.132426\\
9&1.240600\\
10&1.343016
\end{array}
$$
Asymptotically, the expected number of zero crossings is
$$
\frac{2n^{1/2}}\pi+C+\frac1{6\pi n^{1/2}}-\frac1{120\pi n^{3/2}}-\frac1{840\pi n^{5/2}}+\frac5{8064\pi n^{7/2}}+\frac1{4224\pi n^{9/2}}
$$
where $C=-0.686843660075987093$

Comment: I have written a simulation in Mathematica, and the numbers in the table are matched well.

Comment: Oh, of course, a sum of iid Gaussians is Gaussian. That is such a simple way to start it. Nice calculus tricks, though. I would not have expected the answer to be trigonometric.

Comment: robJohn, could you explain the asymptotic expansion?

Comment: I used the series $\tan^{-1}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5-\frac{x^7}7+\dots$ and the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to compute the asymptotic expansion to $O\left(n^{-23/2}\right)$. I evaluated $C$ by subtracting that expansion at $n=1000$ from $e_{1000}$.

Comment: thanks, I now understand the expansion and  the constant C involved in the expansion

Comment: If n was ~billion steps, could this form some type of randomness test?

Comment: I would rather try to rescale with \(sqrt{n}\). The result should be related to a halfnormal distribution. In the worst case, i am sure you would find something in Feller about that.

Comment: @PeterKeller This sounds like a great approach for an alternative answer to this question.  Why not write it up?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Well, the asymptotics just shows that $e_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges to $2/pi$. The result for random Walk with +1 or -1 with equal probability has a similar limit result, but with the the square root of the result above. I haven't yet checked all the computations done above. I somehow had in mind, that the results should be the same.