# Expected number of zero crossings in 3 value random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let's say we have a 1D random walk starting at the origin where we go up $1$ with probability $1/5$, down $1$ with probability $1/5$, and stay put with probability $3/5$.

If we walk $n$ steps, what's the expected number of times we reach zero?

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338097/expected-number-of-times-random-walk-crosses-0-line)'s a similar question, where instead they assume we move based on a continuous distribution.

I tried turning my discrete distribution into a continuous one using the pdf

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{5}\delta(x+1) + \frac{3}{5}\delta(x) + \frac{1}{5}\delta(x-1),$$

but the approach in that question didn't seem to work out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you count staying at zero as "reaching" zero, or are you interested in the expected number of returns to zero, counting each (possibly extended) stay at zero as one?

Comment: @joriki Yes, I'm counting staying at zero as "reaching" zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, the expected number of visits to the origin is the sum over the expected number of visits to the origin after $0\lt l\le n$ steps. That's the probability of taking $j$ up steps and $j$ down steps and staying put $l-2j$ times, summed for $0\le 2j\le l$, so the total is

$$
\sum_{l=1}^n\left(\frac35\right)^l\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac l2\right\rfloor}\binom l{j,j,l-2j}3^{-2j}\;.
$$

I'm not aware that this can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks for this! Don't we also need to somehow incorporate the 1/5 probabilities into the formula?

Comment: @ZapMathigan: Yes, certainly, sorry, it should have been $5^{-n}$ instead of $5^{-l}$; fixed.

Comment: Actually I think your first answer was correct. Using your ideas, I had a double sum with summand `Binomial[2 j, j] Binomial[l, 2 j] (1/5)^(2 j) (3/5)^(l - 2 j)`. That simplifies to your first answer. I did some simulations and it seems correct.

Comment: @ZapMathigan: Right, you had me confused for a moment there :-) You were right that we need to incorporate the $\frac15$ probabilities, but I'd already incorporated them. I reverted the edit.