# How to elegantly predict average number of zero crossings for cumulative sum plot for N flips of a coin where heads is +1 and tails is -1

Tags: probability, statistics

I believe the same question was asked in question 1338097, but I think the answer might be flawed. However, I'm not familiar with the terms and have only the most basic understanding of probability theory. I know that if you create a sequence of +1s and -1s by flipping a fair coin N times (e.g. heads for +1, tails for -1) the number of possible sequences, ranging from all +1s to all -1s is 2^N. And assuming the sequence is truly random, each of the possible sequences will have the same probability of occurring. Therefore, if you generated each of the 2^N possible sequences, performing the cumulative summation process for each and counting the number of times the sum crosses 0 (i.e. 1 -> 0 -> -1 or -1 -> 0 -> 1), then dividing that count by 2^N gives the answer I'm looking for. And for N = 5 or less, you could even figure it out on a piece of paper in a few minutes if you weren't a computer programmer or didn't have a computer. But I wrote a program to do it and here's my table of answers for N = 2 to 10:

```
 N    average 0 crossings
 2    none (takes at least 3 moves to cross 0)
 3    .25 
 4    .25
 5    .4375
 6    .4375
 7    .59375
 8    .59375
 9    .730469
 10   .730469
```

And since the process to come up with these answers involves nothing more than simple arithmetic, I believe these answers are as exact as single-precision floating point operations can give. Of course, the problem with this method is that the computer is brought to its knees for values of N higher than about 30. But I don't care about being that exact. Approximations to, say, 5 decimal places would be fine. Is there an elegant solution that would have my computer spitting out the answer for values of N greater than 100 or even 1000?

Comment: The answer given in the linked question correctly answers the *question* in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338097/expected-number-of-times-random-walk-crosses-0-line).  Your question is not the same question as the proposed duplicate.  In the linked question, the distance travelled in each step of the random walk is normally distributed.  That is not the case for you where you always explicitly travel either $+1$ or $-1$.  You are performing a discrete random walk.  Theirs is continuous.

Comment: You would want to take a look at Feller's Probability Volume 1, somewhere around page 60 I believe.

Comment: Hmm.. at first glance, the setup for this seems equivalent to a simple random walk. In that case you may want to apply the reasoning used in solving the generalized ballot problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be the number of zero crossings for a sequence of $n$ coin flips. We note that $\mathbb{E}X_n = \mathbb{E}X_{n-1}$ when $n$ is even, since the last step can't complete a zero crossing and therefore can be ignored.

Assume $n$ is odd. Let $S_k$ be the total after the $k$ steps and let $Z_k$ be an indicator for whether there is a zero crossing at index $k$, i.e. $$Z_k = \mathbb{1}\{S_{k-1}=\pm 1, S_{k}=0, S_{k+1}=\mp 1\}.$$

We can write the number of zero crossings, $X_n$, as the sum of these indicators:

$$X_n =\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}Z_{2i}.$$

By linearity of expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}X_n =\sum_{i=1}^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}P(S_{2i-1}=\pm 1, S_{2i}=0, S_{2i+1}=\mp 1)=2\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}P(S_{2i-1}= 1, S_{2i}=0, S_{2i+1}=-1),$$

where the last line follows because the random walk is symmetric.

Since $S_{k}\sim 2\text{Binom}(k,\frac{1}{2})-k,$ we get

\begin{align*}P(S_{2i-1}= 1, S_{2i}=0, S_{2i+1}=-1)&=P(S_{2i-1}=1)P(S_{2i}=0, S_{2i+1}=-1\vert S_{2i-1}=1)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\binom{2i-1}{i}\frac{1}{2^{2i-1}},
\end{align*}

so for odd $n$, we have

$$\mathbb{E}X_n = \mathbb{E}X_{n+1} =\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{2i-1}{i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}.$$
Wolfram Alpha gives a closed form for this sum:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-1 + 2^{-n} (n+1) \binom{n}{ \frac{n+1}{2}}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you @user51547, I coded what you gave above and it works perfectly! For n=35 my brute force program takes about 3 hours to come up with the answer 1.87709. Using your very elegant solution my computer spits it out instantly! And to get it to work for n=500 or n=1000, I simply had to change the return type of my factorial routine from double to long double. It overflows for n=1000000, which is no surprise, so I guess I'll just say "thanks a thousand!!!"

Comment: +1. You might be able to shorten this by saying that the probability of a zero-crossing $\mathbb P(S_{k-1}=\pm 1, S _k=0, S_{k+1}=\mp1) =\frac12 \mathbb P(S_k=0)$ at least when $k>0$: you reach $0$ and then with probability $\frac12$ need to continue to the opposite side.  $\mathbb P(S_k=0)$ is a simple central binomial probability